# Using dictionary in .NET

Tags: c#, dictionary

can i add one dictionary object to another dictionary.
I mean i am having a check box list whose checked item are being added to a dictionary object by using foreach loop. in the same page i am having some more variable which are added to anther dictionary object now i have two dictionary object which i need to pass to a method but i want to know can i add check box dictionary object to another dictionary object and can be passed to a method and if so then on other end how can i open it back to retrieve the all items.

or other good solution please suggest

Comment: You are asking if you can nest one Dictionary in another, or just how to pass two dictionarys as one parameter?

Comment: yes yes you are true i want to know how to pass two dictionarys as one parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is unrelated data, then use two different Dictionaries and pass them separately. Is there a good reason why you would want to only pass one Dictionary?  I think KISS applies here.

Comment: yes u are true there is no good reason to do so ,i am passing them separate

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to pass them both together just pass a list of them like:

```
List<Dictionary<int, string>>
```